# python 2.7's logging.info(string) and newline characters

Tags: python

Does python 2.7's logging.info(string) (import logging) automatically strip newline characters from the given string? If not, is there a command to make it behave like that? If so which command is that?

Thank's a lot!

Comment: yourString.replace("\n", "") will remove all newline characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will not automatically strip newlines.

You can remove them yourself by calling the `.replace()` method of the string:

```
without_newlines = my_string.replace("\n", "")
```

(Another, slightly more potentially efficient option is to use the deletion feature of `.translate()`, but `.replace()` may be more readable if you don't care about high levels of optimization.)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to to pydoc: [logging.debug](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug)

The format is like what you write in **print()**